# Ansible source virtualenvwrapper

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to source virtualenvwrapper file on a remote server using Ansible.

```
- name: Source virtualenvwrapper
  shell: >
    . /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

But I am getting `Bad Substitution` error. Any ideas on fixing it..??

Comment: If you log in the server and try to manually execute `. /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, does it work? (Note: even if you fix the problem, I doubt virtualenvwrapper is going to work properly the way you are trying it. But let's fix one problem at a time.)

Comment: Yeah when I manually run the command, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible is not explicitly using `/bin/sh` and the shell module uses `shell=True` as an argument to **subprocess**. So probably Python subprocess uses /bin/sh and not all shell settings. There is an option for shell module named **executable** that can be used to specify another shell.

Try this one:

```
- name: Source virtualenvwrapper
  shell: >
    . /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```